# Powershell renaming files containing repeating pattern (that has to be removed for the first occurrence)

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching, rename

I would like to rename a bunch of files containing a pattern that could be repeated inside the filename. The Pattern to remove it everything from the start the the first "dot + space".
ex: "wxxdv xcvxcv. sdfsdf. sd.txt" to become "sdfsdf. sd.txt" (removing the first occurrence of "wxxdv xcvxcv. " that is terminated by `"dot + space" = ". "`)
ex: "rond M., Bilou. `arrival 1901.txt`" should become "`arrival 1901.txt`" (**remove** "rond M., Bilou. ")

I found that the following command that shouln't be too far from my goal (but doesn't work):

```
dir *.txt | mi -dest {($_.Basename -replace '^[A-z]+\.\s','').Trim() + $_.Extension}
```

Bonus question, is there any way of seeing the result without executing the renaming (a sort of preview of the result)

Thanks, it's my first attempt to use powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$t="rond M., Bilou. arrival 1901.txt"
$formatedText=$t.Substring(([regex]::split($t, '\.\s')[0]).Length+2)
write-host $formatedText

arrival 1901.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kayasax, but I cannot pipe your command to process all the files... Is this something like this:
dir *.pdf | mi -dest {($_.Basename.Substring(([regex]::split($t, '\.\s')[0]).Length+2)) + $_.Extension}

Comment: i would say ` mi -dest {($_.Basename.Substring(([regex]::split($_.basename, '\.\s')[0]).Length+2)) + $_.Extension`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my Bonus question

> is there any way of seeing the result without executing the renaming

is to use the "-WhatIf" switch of the Move-Item command (mi), so the command would be:

```
dir *.pdf | mi -WhatIf -dest {($_.Basename.Substring(([regex]::split($_.basename, '\.\s')[0]).Length+2)) + $_.Extension}
```